# Response.AddHeader attachment doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net

here's the code I have:

```
                Response.Clear();
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=file.xlsx");
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
                Response.End();
```

The problem is that when this code is run (On button click) I do not a file for download in my browser (tried in Chrome \ IE).

pck is an excel file (Generated with [epplus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) library).
I don't even know how to debug this part of the code. it's doing nothing.

Here's the error I'm getting in my browser:

> Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException:
>   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message
>   received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this
>   error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(),
>   response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled.
>
> Details: Error parsing near 'PKX��@ϖ�'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are using an update panel. You cannot download a file when performing an Async Postback. Add the button which will download the file as Postback trigger for the update panel.

Comment: I think ramesh is probably right.  Update panels communicate with a pipe delimited format that includes information about control to update, content to update with, etc.  When you modify the response, the client side update panel related code cannot parse the response and you get an error similar to the one you posted.

Comment: Yeah, looks like this is the problem. I was able to fix it by registering postback control:           ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).RegisterPostBackControl(this.button1);

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track.  I think you're missing a couple of lines:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=file.xlsx");
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
Response.Flush();
Response.Close();
Response.End();
```